# How to add location specific data to markers on a map

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am pretty new to d3.js and also to forums. So I apologize if this question has already been asked before. I am trying to create a US map that has markers for stores and when you hover over those stores, data pertaining to that location should pop up. Ultimately I am trying to add a vertical bar chart to those markers, but for now I will settle to just show name and address of a store so I can break the process down to fully understand it. I have two json files:
 1. us.json
 2. newstorelocations.json (This contains the name, address, lat and lon of each location)

What I have so far is a map of the US with markers for each stores. When you hover over it, the markers turn red. The code for that is here:
http://bl.ocks.org/binishbaig/a4d93ddbb599eaf5f20a

The code for what I have tried and think it should work is here:
http://bl.ocks.org/binishbaig/e154f91c726fb8326c3b

I just don't know why the second one is not showing names of the stores when you hover over it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: In your `mouseover` handler, you are setting the `text` of the tooltip to `function(d) { return d.name; }`, the problem here is that `d` will be a local that won't get set.  Instead, make the call `.text(d.name)`.  Updated gist at http://bl.ocks.org/benlyall/d7066fb0fd4f822baf2a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue happened on line 122. The **d** variable was part of the anonymous function, so it's not the one defined above it. I solved the issue passing the name attribute of the **d** (d.name) variable as value to the *text* method rather than using an anonymous function.

Other problem was related to the #tooltip selector (line 57 [your code](https://gist.github.com/binishbaig/e154f91c726fb8326c3b) ). You defined it after the **map** element on line 58, so it wasn't shown when pointing over the coordinates. I solved it by moving the #tooltip selector on top of the map element.

[My solution: DEMO](http://bl.ocks.org/anthony2727/93ccd5e1248566ec08d8)

I hope you find my answer helpful. 
Thanks.

Comment: Ah moving it before the map element makes sense.I had initially tried that (d.name) but it wasn't displaying anything so I figured there was something wrong with that line and started trying different things. I have data in a third file that contains products and price for each store. The variable StoreName exist in newstorelocations.json and the third file. Any clue how can I make a bar chart displaying price and product for each store location? I am guessing I would have to write a separate function creating the chart, and then pass it into that variable d but that's purely a guess.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is on line 122 of your document. It is trying to read the attribute "name" of an undefined variable/object. This means that the variable d, which you are expected to be passed as an argument to your anonymous function there, is not actually being passed. See if just removing d from anonymous function(d){ return d.name; } definition on line 122 allows you to access the object d from the scope in which we can see it is accessible (since we see the object being logged to the console). If that doesn't work, then you will need to find another way to access that object, for which there is more than one solution.